# Setting default encoding to ISO in Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

I am working on a legacy project based on ZF1 which uses ISO-8859-1 charset. Also the servers default encoding is ISO. New modules should be implemented using ZF2. How can the default encoding e.g. for escapers etc. be set globally to anything else than UTF-8 in ZF2?

Comment: So far it seems there is no robust way to change the encoding globally. The way to go seems to be to implement new functionality in ZF2 using utf-8 and keep using latin1 encoding in the database. More infirmation can be found on 

http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/ZF2-Set-default-encoding-to-ISO-in-Zend-Framework-2-td4657670.html;cid=1350893416289-363

Answer (score 1):

If you use escapers directly in your modules, this will be a problem. If you use only the view helpers, there is an option to set the encoding.

Every escaper view helper (`EscapeCss`, `EscapeHtml` and so on) extend from the `Zend\View\Helper\Escaper\AbstractHelper`. This class has a method `setEncoding()`. because the encoding is not shared between all helper instances, you must set them individually, but you are able to set the encoding there.

For example, you can set the correct encoding during bootstrap. Say you have your Application module:

```
<?php

namespace Application;

use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module
{
  public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
  {
    $app = $e->getApplication();
    $sm  = $app->getServiceManager;

    $manager  = $sm->get('ViewHelperManager');
    $plugins  = array(escapehtml', 'escapehtmlattr', 'escapejs', 'escapecss', 'escapeurl');
    $encoding = 'ISO-8859-1';

    foreach ($plugins as $name) {
      $plugin = $manager->get($name);
      $plugin->setEncoding($encoding);
    }
  }
}
```

This should correct all plugins to the ISO-8859-1 encoding. If any of your modules, or any 3rd party modules, use the escaper view helpers, the ISO-8859-1 encoding will be used.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. This seems to work basically. But if you use the "StringTrim" Filter it still depends on utf-8. I guess because the StringTrim Filter does not take encoding into acount. You can reproduce it with the following test. Can this somehow be overcome or do I need to write my own StrinTrim Filter

$filter = new \Zend\Filter\StringTrim();
var_dump($filter->filter('äöüas'));

Comment: The same seems to apply to the StringToLower and HtmlEntities Filters as well as validators like StringLength. I can not see how this can be set globally  onBootstrap. So far it seems that this must be explicitly set each time when used. Is that true?